# The directive name [] is not valid. Directive names must only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores

Tags: laravel

I got the error below after installing `bonecms/laravel-captcha` package. How can I fix it?

> The directive name [] is not valid. Directive names must only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores.

[image: Image showing error message "The directive name [] is not valid. Directive names must only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores."]

Comment: You did not provide many details. My guess is that you're on Laravel >= 6x and that your config is cached. Re-cache your config and try again. `php artisan config:cache`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-cache your config.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

If you are:

1. Using Laravel >= 6x, and
2. Installing a package that has a config and uses the `mergeConfigFrom()` function in the service provider, and
3. Have your config cached before the package was installed

Then you need to re-cache your config after installing the package. If your config is already cached when the package is installed, the config provided by the new package will never be read until the config is re-cached.

Comment: @ashok If this resolved your issue, you can mark it as the accepted answer, which will help others with the same issue know this works to fix it.